# Isa 28:12 hebrew word margeah (meaning - refreshing) translated to greek suntrimma (meaning -destruction) why?

Tags: greek, hebrew, isaiah

In Isaiah 28:12 we have

> ToH413 whomH834 he said,H559 ThisH2063 is the restH4496 wherewith ye may cause the wearyH5889 to rest;H5117 and thisH2063 is the ***refreshing:H4774*** yet they wouldH14 notH3808 hear.H8085

Here they have the strong's number H4774
margē‛āh: A feminine noun referring to a place of rest. It refers to a state of relaxation and a cessation from toil, fighting, and worry (Isa_28:12).

in the Apostolic Bible Polyglot we have

> Isa 28:12  sayingG3004 to it,G1473 This is G3778 theG3588 restG371.1 to theG3588 one hungering,G3983 andG2532 thisG3778 is theG3588 ***destruction;G4938*** andG2532 they did notG3756 wantG2309 to hear.G191
>
> σύντριμμα
> súntrimma; gen. suntrímmatos, neut. noun from suntríbō (G4937), to break into pieces, crush. A crushing, fracture, breaking to pieces, destruction

How did it go from relaxation to destruction/calamity
from margeah to suntrimma?

Comment: Thank you for your answer Der Übermensch, exactly what I was looking for. I was trying to connect Acts 3:19 with Isa 28:12 but the Septuagint was making it difficult. :)

Answer (score 1):

Aquila<sup>1</sup> translated the Hebrew מַרְגֵּעָה into Greek as ἀνάψυξις, meaning “cooling, relief, respite”;<sup>2</sup> the Vulgate, *refrigerium*, which is essentially the equivalent of the Greek ἀνάψυξις;<sup>3</sup> Symmachus, ἠρεμία, meaning “rest.”<sup>4</sup> The Isaiah Dead Sea Scroll (1QIsa<sup>a</sup>) has the same Hebrew word in question.

[image: 1QIsaa Dead Sea Scroll, Isaiah 28:12]

According to Gesenius, מַרְגֵּעָה is derived from the verb רָגַע. This verb seems to have a connotation of stillness. In binyan Nifʿal, it can mean “to rest or be still.”<sup>5</sup> In binyan Hifʿil, it can mean “to still, make still, to give rest” (transitive) or “to rest, dwell quietly” (intransitive).<sup>6</sup>

So, why σύντριμμα? σύντριμμα can mean destruction or ruin, but also break or fracture. The related verb is συντρίβω, which can mean “to crush, shatter, break.”<sup>7</sup> It seems to me that the only plausible reason for σύντριμμα (however wrong it may be) in Isa. 28:12 is that the translator derived its meaning from רָגַע in Job 7:5. Whether it truly means “broken” there is arguable, but it seems the committee that produced the King James Version thought so.

---

#### Footnotes

<sup>1</sup> Field, p. [479](https://archive.org/details/origenishexaplor02origuoft/page/479)
<sup>2</sup> LSJ, p. 127
<sup>3</sup> Lewis & Short, p. [1548](https://archive.org/details/harperslatindict00lewi/page/1548); cf. 2 Tim. 1:16
<sup>4</sup> LSJ, p. 777
<sup>5</sup> Gesenius, p. [507](https://books.google.com/books?id=E80OAAAAQAAJ&pg=PG507#v=onepage&q&f=true)
<sup>6</sup> *ibid.*
<sup>7</sup> BDAG, p. 976; LSJ, p. 1728

#### References

Arndt, William; Bauer, Walter; Danker, Frederick William. *A Greek-English Lexicon of the New Testament and Other Early Christian Literature.* 3rd ed. Chicago: U of Chicago P, 2000.

Field, Frederick. [*Origenis Hexaplorum.*](https://archive.org/details/origenishexaplor02origuoft/) Vol. 2. Oxonii: E Typographeo Clarendoniano, 1875.

Gesenius, Heinrich Friedrich Wilhelm. [*Gesenius’s Hebrew and Chaldee Lexicon to the Old Testament Scriptures.*](https://books.google.com/books?id=E80OAAAAQAAJ) Trans. Tregelles, Samuel Prideaux. London: Bagster, 1860.

Lewis, Charlton T.; Short, Charles. [*Harper’s Latin Dictionary: A New Latin Dictionary Founded on the Translation of Freund’s Latin-German Lexicon.*](https://archive.org/details/harperslatindict00lewi/) New York: American Book, 1879.